# Is there a way to change the default timeout apart from --timeout flag for helm install/upgrade?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

According to helm [install](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_install/) and [upgrade](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_upgrade/) doc , the way to change the default timeout of 5m0s is to use the flag --timeout . But is there any way we can increase this timeout , maybe in some configuration file or cluster setting where we can change the default value of 5m0s to a higher duration somehow?

Comment: TLDR; no, you have to use `--timeout` to override default `5m0s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It cannot be changed globally and should be used per action.
See docs: https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#helpful-options-for-installupgraderollback